# Webpage connection - coffee restaurant

Tags: wireless, connection, router

I am in a coffee shop, and the Wireless connection doesn't display the webpage connection automatically. Is there an easy way to configure that those kind of page pop-up by itself?

Comment: This is likely an issue with their access point. I find that often when I cannot see the access page I get it when on a browser I try this address: 192.168.0.1 as this is the standard IP of many access points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to access any **un**secured¹ web sites yet? Many public wireless hotspots require you to agree to their terms of service and redirect you to their terms of service for that purpose upon you first page request. However, this can only work if you try to access unsecured sites; secured connections are simply prohibited and terminated before your agreement.

Any valid unsecured URL will do, e. g. https://askubuntu.com/.

---

¹ Secure connections have a URL starting with `https://` and most web browsers display a lock symbol before it in the address bar. Unsecured connections have URLs starting with `http://` (note the missing `s`), though many web browsers now simply omit that part, and no such lock symbols.

Comment: I have already fixed my problem, but next time, I could try to access an unsecured web site and I'll be redirected to the webpage connection. Am I right? I think this is right, because I'd tried with http://math.stackexchange.com/ and It works. However, it seems that idea doesn't all time.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean. Obviously I can’t be sure what setup the wireless hotspot has so this all depends one one big but likely true assumption. As for http://math.stackexchange.com/, you need to make sure that you didn’t choose `https://math.stackexchange.com/` accidentally (either manually or from Firefox’ “Awesome bar” that suggests previously and popular web pages) or that you have a browser add-on like HTTPS-Everywhere that redirects you automatically to the secure version of a page if one is known to be available and working.

Comment: Ok, that's awesome! It works perfectly